# create a JSON file that browsers will save as JSON

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json, browser

I know I can do the following to generate a JSON (or, in similar fashion, XML) page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo (file_get_contents('some.json', true));
?>
```

However, I need the user to be able to save the file in their browser (using File > Save or similar) and have the browser default to a `.json` (or `.xml`) extension, not a `.txt` or `.php` or whatever their browser defaults to.

Is this possible in php or in javascript?  Perhaps there's a way to modify the url?

e.g. `g.co/index.php` becomes `g.co/index.php/some.json` OR `g.co/some.json` so the browser can use the appropriate file name or extension.

Comment: You have to redirect "some.json" to "some.php" at your web server (while keeping some.json in browser URL). I think it can be done by configuring .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would adding a [content-disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header work for you?

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="some.json"');
```